# Google AutoML Table exported model download problem

Tags: model, download, export, automl

I have been trying to download the exported Google AutoML table model using gsutil command following Google document, but getting an error with the subfolder named timestamp. Google documents say remove the timestamp after downloading, but I cannot download for timestamp problem. The following below is the screenshot showing my problem.

```
D:\>gsutil cp -r gs://location_uscentral1/ MIDPML_export2/* ./exported2
Copying gs://location_uscentral1/MIDPML_export2/model-3253410926124072960/tf-saved-model/2021-05-08T08:16:04.207777Z/batch_predict_metadata.pb...
OSError: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

While trying to use the mv command to remove the timestamp in cloud storage with the following command, it is again rejecting as follows:

```
D:\>gsutil mv gs:// location_uscentral1/MIDPML_export2/model-3253410926124072960/tf-saved-model/2021-05-08T08:16:04.207777Z gs:// location_uscentral1/MIDPML_export2/model-3253410926124072960/tf-saved-model/2021-05-08T08:16:04.207777Z/cfolder
CommandException: "mv" command does not support provider-only URLs.
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem but was able to download locally with the following:

```
gsutil cp -r "gs://my-bucket/my-subfolders/model-7384320092/tf-saved-model/2021-05-14T23:50:42.383987Z/*" .
```

It seems that encasing the gs file path in quotes helped, plus not including the timestamp number in my system directory structure (Windows).